# How can I tell if I need a transit visa in Hong Kong?

Tags: visas, transit, bangladeshi-citizens

My travel route:

Singapore (origin) --> Hong Kong (transit) --> Seoul, South Korea (destination)

I am flying Cathay Pacific, and I am holding a Bangladeshi passport. I am getting conflicting information from various websites. The Cathay Pacific website states that we don't need a transit visa if we are flying CX all the way. However, the HK immigration web page says everyone needs a transit visa. Could anyone advise please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [HK Immigration web site](http://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/visit-transit/visit-visa-entry-permit.html#notes), which is probably the most authoritative on the subject, says:

> All nationals (except holders of Diplomatic and Official passports) are required to hold a valid visa for the HKSAR for whatever purpose (including those who are in transit and remain on the airside). Holders of Diplomatic and Official passports may visit the HKSAR visa-free for a stay not exceeding 14 days.

So unless you have a diplomatic or official passport, you'll need a transit visa.

Comment: thanks for your reply. the confusion here is that, according to: http://visados.com/en/visa-for-Hong-Kong-3#67

Comment: 1. TWOV is permissible for travellers in direct transit provided they have valid documents for their next trip; onward tickets with confirmed reservations; are continuing their trip to a third country within 48 hours; and are not leaving the transit area. Overnight facilities are not available. Personnel of the coming transporting carrier must meet travellers on arrival to make sure that they stay in transit area to avoid being presented to the Immigration Authorities;
1.1. TWOV does not apply to travellers with normal passports provided they are citizens of Angola, Bangladesh,

Comment: i also did a check through the IATA website (http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/travelinformation.php) and got the reply that "Nationals of Bangladesh traveling on Cathay Pacific (CX) or Cathay Dragon (KA) are allowed to transit without a visa if
passenger has a valid visa or proof of residency of Australia, Canada, Japan, Korea (Rep.), New Zealand, United Kingdom, USA
or a Schengen Member State."

Comment: @scarlett if I had a decision to make based on either a commercial web site, or the country's/region's Immigration web site, I would tend to believe the Immigration – they're the guys who make the decision. On the other hand, Cathay knows what they are doing (usually, but not always). I've seen flights from Seoul, with, among transfers, Dhaka being listed. It could be that CX/KA get a free pass.

Comment: @dda - I'd normally agree that the gov site is best, but Cathay's website, updated 4 months ago, is reasonably clear in its assertion that as long as OP has a visa for South Korea (or the other listed countries), is travelling only on Cathay / Cathay Dragon + meets a couple of other criteria, then they don't need a visa: https://www.cathaypacific.com/cx/en_AE/travel-information/travel-preparation/travel-advisories/hong-kong-visa-requirements-transit-twov.html

Remember that in this instance, it's Cathay staff in Bangladesh (and on the return in South Korea) that will make the decision.